# ASP.NET vNext site fails to run under IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a reasonably standard website that I've build under ASP.NET 5 rc1-update1.  I deploy it to IIS (tried both 8 and 7.5) and attempting to hit it never gets past `Waiting for localhost` stage.  So I turned on logging by setting `stdoutLogEnabled="true"` in the `httpPlatform` element of the web.config file and saw the following error:

```
Error: Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting'. Available commands: web, ef.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoadFile(String path, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(String path)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.LoadFile(String assemblyPath)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.PackageAssemblyLoader.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName, IAssemblyLoadContext loadContext)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.PackageAssemblyLoader.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.LoaderContainer.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.DefaultLoadContext.LoadAssembly(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoaderCache.GetOrAdd(AssemblyName name, Func`2 factory)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.LoadAssemblyImpl(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.ResolveAssembly(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
   at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)
```

It can't seem to find Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.dll files.  So I built a test website - just defaults from Visual Studio and deployed it to IIS and it ran fine, so it was obviously able to find that file.

I ran `procmon` to see where it looks for that file and found the following:

[image]

For my site (marked Failing), dnx.exe looks in `\approot\runtimes` and then it gives up.  In the Test site, it also looks in `\approot\runtimes`, can't find it there, but then it goes to look in `\approot\packages` and there it is and the website is now up.

I've compared various configuration files between my site and the test site and don't see any obvious differences or why dnx.exe would look in `\approot\packages` for the test site, but not for my site.

What am I missing?  How can I get dnx.exe to find the DLLs in the right directories?

Comment: Have you installed the HttpPlatformHandler?

Comment: @JonTheMon The HttpPlatformHandler 1.2?  Yes.  Otherwise the test site wouldn't run either.

Comment: I interpret the error message as following `dnx` loaded `Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.dll`, but it try to start command defined in `"commands"` section of `project.json` file, which contains only definitions of commends `web` and `ef`, which is correct. The problem is that your current configuration of arguments of dnx in `web.config` try to start **the command with the name `Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting`** (instead of the `web` commend). I think that you should verify `launchSettings.json` or `hosting.json` to find the reason of the problem.

Comment: If you use Process Monitor then it would be interesting to switch from File part to Task part and to find the parameters with, which one started `dnx`. I interpret the error message so that you use `dnx Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting` instead of `dnx web`.